# How to write generic function with Scala Quill.io library

Tags: scala, generics, quill.io

I am trying to implement generic method in Scala operating on database using Quill.io library. Type `T` will be only case classes what works with Quill.io.

```
def insertOrUpdate[T](inserting: T, equality: (T,T) => Boolean)(implicit ctx: Db.Context): Unit = {
  import ctx._

  val existingQuery = quote {
    query[T].filter { dbElement: T =>
      equality(dbElement, inserting)
    }
  }
  val updateQuery = quote {
    query[T].filter { dbElement =>
      equality(dbElement, lift(inserting))
    }.update(lift(inserting))
  }
  val insertQuery = quote { query[T].insert(lift(inserting)) }

  val existing = ctx.run(existingQuery)
  existing.size match {
    case 1 => ctx.run(updateQuery)
    case _ => ctx.run(insertQuery)

  }
}
```

But I am getting two types of compile error

```
Error:(119, 12) Can't find an implicit `SchemaMeta` for type `T`
  query[T].filter { dbElement: T =>

Error:(125, 33) Can't find Encoder for type 'T'
    equality(dbElement, lift(inserting))
```

How can I modify my code to let it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the [issue](https://github.com/getquill/quill/issues/806) that @VojtechLetal mentioned in his answer you have to use macros.

I added code implementing generic insert or update in my [example Quill project](https://github.com/mxl/quill-example/tree/4723a5e482efb75b04371ad1d6410219b0893364/src/main/scala/io/getquill/example/genericInsertOrUpdate).

It defines [`trait Queries`](https://github.com/mxl/quill-example/blob/4723a5e482efb75b04371ad1d6410219b0893364/src/main/scala/io/getquill/example/genericInsertOrUpdate/Queries.scala) that's [mixed into context](https://github.com/mxl/quill-example/blob/4723a5e482efb75b04371ad1d6410219b0893364/src/main/scala/io/getquill/example/genericInsertOrUpdate/package.scala#L6):

```
trait Queries {
  this: JdbcContext[_, _] =>
  def insertOrUpdate[T](entity: T, filter: (T) => Boolean): Unit = macro InsertOrUpdateMacro.insertOrUpdate[T]
}
```

This trait uses [macro](https://github.com/mxl/quill-example/blob/4723a5e482efb75b04371ad1d6410219b0893364/macro/src/main/scala/io/getquill/example/genericInsertOrUpdate/InsertOrUpdateMacro.scala) that's implementing your code with minor changes:

```
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.{Context => MacroContext}

class InsertOrUpdateMacro(val c: MacroContext) {

  import c.universe._

  def insertOrUpdate[T](entity: Tree, filter: Tree)(implicit t: WeakTypeTag[T]): Tree =
    q"""
      import ${c.prefix}._
      val updateQuery = ${c.prefix}.quote {
        ${c.prefix}.query[$t].filter($filter).update(lift($entity))
      }
      val insertQuery = quote {
        query[$t].insert(lift($entity))
      }
      run(${c.prefix}.query[$t].filter($filter)).size match {
          case 1 => run(updateQuery)
          case _ => run(insertQuery)
      }
      ()
    """
}
```

Usage [examples](https://github.com/mxl/quill-example/blob/4723a5e482efb75b04371ad1d6410219b0893364/src/main/scala/io/getquill/example/genericInsertOrUpdate/package.scala):

```
import io.getquill.{PostgresJdbcContext, SnakeCase}

package object genericInsertOrUpdate {
  val ctx = new PostgresJdbcContext[SnakeCase]("jdbc.postgres") with Queries

  def example1(): Unit = {
    val inserting = Person(1, "")
    ctx.insertOrUpdate(inserting, (p: Person) => p.name == "")
  }

  def example2(): Unit = {
    import ctx._
    val inserting = Person(1, "")
    ctx.insertOrUpdate(inserting, (p: Person) => p.name == lift(inserting.name))
  }
}
```

P.S. Because `update()` returns number of updated records your code can be simplified to:

```
class InsertOrUpdateMacro(val c: MacroContext) {

  import c.universe._

  def insertOrUpdate[T](entity: Tree, filter: Tree)(implicit t: WeakTypeTag[T]): Tree =
    q"""
      import ${c.prefix}._
      if (run(${c.prefix}.quote {
        ${c.prefix}.query[$t].filter($filter).update(lift($entity))
      }) == 0) {
          run(quote {
            query[$t].insert(lift($entity))
          })
      }
      ()
    """
}
```

Comment: Your example needed only one change in `InsertOrUpdateMacro`. I was getting error from ambiguous import if `ctx._`. So I removes this import from your macro and added explicit calls where needed: `def insertOrUpdate[T](entity: Tree, filter: Tree)(implicit t: WeakTypeTag[T]): Tree =
    q"""
      if (${c.prefix}.run(${c.prefix}.quote {
        ${c.prefix}.query[$t].filter($filter).update(${c.prefix}.lift($entity))
      }) == 0) {
       ${c.prefix}.run(quote {
            query[$t].insert(${c.prefix}.lift($entity))
          })
      }
      ()
    """`

Comment: I got this error: Error:scalac: Error: symbol_= inapplicable for <empty>
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: symbol_= inapplicable for <empty>
 at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Tree.symbol_$eq(Trees.scala:54)
 at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Tree.setSymbol(Trees.scala:55)
...
The version from @snilard did not compile. Maybe post a gist or fork the project?

Comment: @mslinn Did you get this error when compiling my example project?

Answer (score 0):

As one of the quill contributors said in this [issue](https://github.com/getquill/quill/issues/806):

> If you want to make your solution **generic** then you have to use **macros** because Quill generates queries at compile time and `T` type has to be resolved at that time.

**TL;DR** The following did not work either, just playing

Anyway... just out of curiosity I tried to fix the issue by following the error which you mentioned. I changed the definition of the function as:

```
def insertOrUpdate[T: ctx.Encoder : ctx.SchemaMeta](...)
```

which yielded the following log

```
[info] PopulateAnomalyResultsTable.scala:71: Dynamic query
[info]       case _ => ctx.run(insertQuery)
[info]  
[error] PopulateAnomalyResultsTable.scala:68: exception during macro expansion: 
[error] scala.reflect.macros.TypecheckException: Found the embedded 'T', but it is not a case class
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers$$anonfun$typecheck$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Typers.scala:34)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Typers$$anonfun$typecheck$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Typers.scala:28)
```

It starts promising, since quill apparently gave up on static compilation and made the query dynamic. I checked the source code of the failing [macro](https://github.com/getquill/quill/blob/master/quill-core/src/main/scala/io/getquill/dsl/MetaDslMacro.scala) and it seems that quill is trying to get a constructor for `T` which is not known in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

For more details see my answer [Generic macro with quill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56917141/651140) or implementation
[CrudMacro](https://github.com/ajozwik/quill-generic/blob/master/macro-quill/src/main/scala/pl/jozwik/quillgeneric/quillmacro/CrudMacro.scala):

Complete project you will find on [quill-generic](https://github.com/ajozwik/quill-generic)

```
   package pl.jozwik.quillgeneric.quillmacro

    import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.{ Context => MacroContext }

    class CrudMacro(val c: MacroContext) extends AbstractCrudMacro {

      import c.universe._

  def callFilterOnIdTree[K: c.WeakTypeTag](id: Tree)(dSchema: c.Expr[_]): Tree =
    callFilterOnId[K](c.Expr[K](q"$id"))(dSchema)

  protected def callFilterOnId[K: c.WeakTypeTag](id: c.Expr[K])(dSchema: c.Expr[_]): Tree = {
    val t = weakTypeOf[K]

    t.baseClasses.find(c => compositeSet.contains(c.asClass.fullName)) match {
      case None =>
        q"$dSchema.filter(_.id == lift($id))"
      case Some(base) =>
        val query = q"$dSchema.filter(_.id.fk1 == lift($id.fk1)).filter(_.id.fk2 == lift($id.fk2))"
        base.fullName match {
          case `compositeKey4Name` =>
            q"$query.filter(_.id.fk3 == lift($id.fk3)).filter(_.id.fk4 == lift($id.fk4))"
          case `compositeKey3Name` =>
            q"$query.filter(_.id.fk3 == lift($id.fk3))"
          case `compositeKey2Name` =>
            query
          case x =>
            c.abort(NoPosition, s"$x not supported")

        }
    }
  }

      def createAndGenerateIdOrUpdate[K: c.WeakTypeTag, T: c.WeakTypeTag](entity: Tree)(dSchema: c.Expr[_]): Tree = {
        val filter = callFilter[K, T](entity)(dSchema)
        q"""
          import ${c.prefix}._
          val id = $entity.id
          val q = $filter
          val result = run(
            q.updateValue($entity)
          )
          if (result == 0) {
            run($dSchema.insertValue($entity).returningGenerated(_.id))
          } else {
            id
          }
        """
      }

      def createWithGenerateIdOrUpdateAndRead[K: c.WeakTypeTag, T: c.WeakTypeTag](entity: Tree)(dSchema: c.Expr[_]): Tree = {
        val filter = callFilter[K, T](entity)(dSchema)
        q"""
          import ${c.prefix}._
          val id = $entity.id
          val q = $filter
          val result = run(
            q.updateValue($entity)
          )
          val newId =
            if (result == 0) {
              run($dSchema.insertValue($entity).returningGenerated(_.id))
            } else {
              id
            }
          run($dSchema.filter(_.id == lift(newId)))
          .headOption
          .getOrElse(throw new NoSuchElementException(s"$$newId"))
        """
      }
    }
```